# Django, routing between master and slave intelligently

Tags: database, django, router

I have an django app that has a front end to input data, and an API to serve data. There is a master/slave setup so I am using the database router to govern write to master and read from slave.

```
import random
from django.conf import settings

class DBMasterSlaveRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if len(settings.DB_SLAVES) >= 1:
            return random.choice(settings.DB_SLAVES)
        else:
            return settings.DB_MASTER

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return settings.DB_MASTER

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        return True
```

The problem I am having is on the front end, user input data and hit save, the page reloads and load the data from slave (this happens very quickly), since there is a lag between master and slave, the load will not reflect the latest input. I don't want to put a delay on page load. Right now I have to add `using('default')` to force to read from master on front end

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Could you cache the data in memcached or save it to the user's session?

Comment: Well that's a work around but I would like to have a more solid solution.

Comment: If you want to read from the slave, you will have to wait for the data to propagate to it and there will be a delay - whether it's in your application, the database or client side.

Comment: The thing is I cannot predict how long the propagation is, it varies, I am looking for a clever routing approach, since the API is on a different app, can I make routing to read/write from master on the frontend and read from slave for API access?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/jbalogh/django-multidb-router, specifically the Pinning middleware and use_master decorator. They seem to do exactly what you need.

Comment: Very cool app, thanks @Enrico

Comment: I have done same setting but data not getting replicated to my slaves (read only) any idea how to do without enforcing it via code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is the answer:

https://github.com/jbalogh/django-multidb-router